# Get OneDrive File ID

Tags: api, live, onedrive

I've written a snapshot tool that upload my screenshots directly to microsoft onedrive (formerly skydrive) and puts the link into my clipboard.
The tool counts up the resource IDs in order to get the link.
Structure is like this

```
https://storage.live.com/items/<cid>!<file id>
```

I wanna know if there is any way via php requests or the onedrive api to get the fileid of the file i just uploaded

Answer (score 2):

When you do a PUT to OneDrive in your snapshot tool there will be a JSON response.  In that response will be id, file name and source URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the LiveConnectClient.GetAsync (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh694251.aspx) method to get the file ID.
Here's an example:

```
LiveConnectClient liveClient = new LiveConnectClient(this.session);
        LiveOperationResult operationResult =
            await liveClient.GetAsync("file.8c8ce076ca27823f.8C8CE076CA27823F!129");
```

Replacing "file.8c8ce..." with the file's friendly name will work.